# Magento 2 module not installing via composer correctly

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

Currently trying to get a staging instance up and running. I have run `./composer install` and it starts installing fine. I added my keys when it asks for me to authenticate with `repo.magento.com` and it installs all the core modules fine, however when it gets to `amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module`. I get this error and I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

```
 - Installing amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module (1.1.1): Downloading (connecting...)


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                         
   Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module/amzn-amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module- 1.1.1.0.zip', aborting.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Should try with Google at the first. Yeah! And then, we can find the doc: https://amzn.github.io/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/installation.html

Following the guide:

[image]

Comment: Hi,After reading your answer I am no closer to solving this. I had already looked at the installation documentaion, however it provided no suggestions for how to troubleshoot this issue. I did also try the command in your screenshot (again), but no such luck.

Comment: The same error with your question or another error? Did you try to remove the module from `composer.json` and try to add it via command line?